# I don't understand why pointer used in cast

Tags: c

I do understand that this statement is casting a unsigned volatile char to a memory address but what I don't understand is the pointer after volatile.

```
#define PORTC *(unsigned char volatile *)(0x1003)
```

Comment: You see this on processors where an I/O port is mapped into a specific memory address, so when you read or write `PORTC` you are exchanging information with the external device.

Answer (score 6):

It says: treat the number `0x1003` as a volatile unsigned character pointer; read or write the (byte) value at that address, depending on how it is used:

```
unsigned char c = PORTC;   // read
PORTC = c + 1;             // write
```

Answer (score 5):

That's not what's happening. Rather, it's interpreting the value 0x1003 as a pointer, and then it's *dereferencing* that pointer to get a value of type `volatile unsigned char`. Essentially, this is a way to access a byte at a fixed memory location. (The "`volatile`" enforces an actual "access" to that memory location, which is a somewhat vaguely defined concept in the standard.)

Answer (score 0):

```
(TYPE*) POINTER
```

is a syntax which is interpreted as a type-cast of pointer.
For example,

```
int m = 4;
char* p_char = (char*)&m;
```

Thus, `p_char` is a pointer to char. If we dereference `p_char`, namely `*p_char`, the binary representation at the position where `p_char` points to will be transformed to a representation of `char`(character). The exact result of this value is undefined. I have no idea what exact value it will return, but it will return something like a weird character `č`.

For a deeper understanding of pointer, I want to emphasize that a pointer is merely one of the interfaces to access entity represented in C++ language and residing on computer memory.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/*
 *  C++ interface to represent entity which resides on computer memory: 
 *      ---------                                             
 *  1) object;
 *  2) pointer;
 *  3) reference;
 *
 *  C++ interpretation of entity through interface: TYPE
 *      --------------                              ----          
 *
 *  What is the function of TYPE?
 *  1) tell compiler the size of an object of this TYPE needed; ( sizeof( int ) -> 4 bytes )
 *  2) when the value of object at which it resides is dereferenced, 
 *     the binary represented value is transformed to some other 
 *     representation value according to the TYPE's interpretation rule; ( if int, interpret it as an int )
 *
 *
 *              +----------------+         
 *              |     0x02105207 |                    
 *              |     0x02105206 |                    
 *              |     0x02105205 |                    
 *       int  n |     0x02105204 |                    
 *              +----------------+                    
 *              |     0x02105203 |                    
 *              |     0x02105202 |                    
 *              |     0x02105201 |                    
 *  ---->int  m |     0x02105200 |                    
 *  |           +----------------+                   
 *  |           |                |                    
 *  |           +----------------+                   
 *  |          ...              ...                    
 *  |           +----------------+                   
 *  ---- int* p |     0x00002298 |                    
 *              +----------------+                   
 *
 *  if the pointer in figure is declared as:
 *
 *       int* p = &m;
 *  
 *  the face of 0x00002298 -> 0x02105200 will not be changed until p is 
 *  assigned to other address value;
 *
 *  
 */

class consecutive_two_int
{
public:
    consecutive_two_int():m(4),n(123){}
    int m;
    int n;
};

int main()
{
    int * p;
    consecutive_two_int obj;
    p = &(obj.m);

    for( int i = 0; i < 8; ++i )
    {
        //  because pointer of char progresses every 1 byte;
        //  increment memory byte by byte through it;
        cout << *(int*)( (char*)p + i ) << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The result, as an example, is:

```
4 // the first defined int
2063597568 // undefined
8060928  // undefined
31488  // undefined
123 // the second defined int
268435456  // undefined
1175453696  // undefined
-465170432  // undefined
```